# Slideshow code seems correct, but app does nothing when executing in emulator

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to build an app for school that queries a website full of random cat pictures and displays them on an emulated android TV. My code looks right, but when I run it I get the spinning wheel showing it's loading and nothing else. I'm not sure what exactly is missing, but hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Code is below:

```
    package com.example.lab2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();


        class CatImages extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
            Bitmap images;
            String id;
            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean on = true;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

                while(on == true) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("https://cataas.com/cat?json=true");
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        InputStream response = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response, "UTF-8"), 8);
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            builder.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        String result = builder.toString();
                        JSONObject image = new JSONObject(result);
                        id = image.getString("id");

                        for (String element : ids) {
                            if (element.contains(id)) {

                                return null;

                            } else {

                                images = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response);
                                File path = new File(directory, id + ".jpg");
                                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
                                images.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                                outputStream.flush();
                                outputStream.close();
                                ids.add(id);

                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                            try {
                                publishProgress(i);
                                Thread.sleep(30);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        return null;
                    }

                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

                for(String element : ids) {
                    if(element.contains(id)) {

                        File openedPic = new File(directory, id + ".jpg");
                        try {
                            Bitmap opener = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(openedPic));
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(opener);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to move logic from onProgressUpdate to onPostExecute. onPostExecute will be called after loading finished

Comment: Your logic is incorrect - this statement `for (String element : ids) {` (in `doInBackground`) would never enter the loop because `ids` is initially empty and the only place anything is added is inside the loop.  The next step is to do 100 `publishProgress` for some unknown reason and loop again.  This is an infinite loop.